# Is there a way to specify a Regex which doesn't match any of the others?

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have something like this:

```
    pattern = new Pattern[6];
    pattern[0] = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(NAME\\:\\s*)\\s(\\w+)");
    pattern[1] = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(AGE\\:\\s*)\\s(\\d+)");
    pattern[2] = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(ADDRESS\\:\\s)(\\w+)");
    pattern[3] = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(BIRTHDAY\\:\\s)(\\d+)\\:(\\d+)\\:(\\d+)");        
    pattern[4] = Pattern.compile("(?=\\s*\\*)(^\\**)");
    pattern[5] = Pattern.compile("\\S+|[^\\s*.+\\s*]");
```

The point of pattern 4 is to capture comments followed by * and the pattern 5 is to capture everything else that the other patterns can't. And then Matcher dp is to check if the pattern is the one expected from the LookAhead returning true or false.

```
    public boolean lookAhead () {
        while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                 Pattern different = Pattern.compile("^[^(\\s*NAME.*)(\\s*AGE.*)(\\s*ADDRESS.*)(\\s*BIRTHDAY.*)]");                
                 Matcher comment = pattern[4].matcher(line);
                 Matcher diff = different.matcher(line);
                 Matcher name = pattern[0].matcher(line);
                 if (comment.find() || different.find() /*|| name.find()*/)               
                     continue;
                    Matcher dp = pattern[0].matcher(line);
                    dpla = dp.find();
                    break;
                 }
        }
        return dpla;
     }
```

The comments are ignored and all random errors like: "feifiejfie" would be too. However if the text is something like "NAME 7987997 GSGSGE 456", this should be considered as an error but it isn't. If name.find is uncommented , it will always work, however it never return false.

Comment: Maybe you should also say how **valid** variations of your input looks like; and what your code should actually be doing. I have a hard time deducting that logic from your regexes. Which already gives a slight hint that maybe your current code isn't exactly easy to read. Meaning: I think that the solution here would be to rework your code dramatically, by focusing on the thing that you really want to know about your input. Thus: please clarify your requirements.

Comment: `pattern[4]` looks wrong to me. It matches "one or more number of asterisks at the start of input", and most of the look ahead is pointless; It's equivalent to `"^\\*+"`

Comment: For the record: please let me know if my answer is helpful to you; or if there is something missing ...

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, thank you for your reply, your idea seems to be very good, however since I have done so much by now, it would take me a very long time to restructure everything, I was able to get an answer for my own question a few hours ago, feel free to check it out and tell me what you think, but I will definitely keep in mind your idea for future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem today! I'm sorry if I didn't explain my question very well, since I had to make up simpler regex to try to explain the question, maybe I missed some important points to get a good answer. This is a very simplified piece of code compared to what I have. The main problem was that although the comments and everything that wasn't the patterns (Pattern 'error' is negating everything that starts with the other patterns) would be detected and would Continue the While cycle, if the pattern started with NAME: or AGE: etc, it means that it would be different from the 'error' pattern, so it wouldn't continue the loop, however that was not supposed to happen because it should only stop the loop if it detects a valid pattern. So what I did was this:

```
Pattern legit = Pattern.compile("^[(\\s*NAME.*)(\\s*AGE.*)(\\s*ADDRESS.*)(\\s*BIRTHDAY.*)");
Matcher leg = legit.matcher(line);
```

The point of this pattern is to determine what is possible in case the comment and error fails. And if they do, they need to check if the valid ones fail:

```
(leg.find() && (!name.find() && !age.find() && !addr.find() && !bd.find())))
```

You can choose the pattern you want to find through the int at the parameter and it will change this:

```
Matcher input = pattern[a].matcher(line);
                 if (!input.find() ...)
```

So everything combined would be something like this:

```
public boolean lookAhead (int a) {
        Pattern error = Pattern.compile("^[^(\\s*NAME.*)(\\s*AGE.*)(\\s*ADDRESS.*)(\\s*BIRTHDAY.*)]");
        Pattern legit = Pattern.compile("^[(\\s*NAME.*)(\\s*AGE.*)(\\s*ADDRESS.*)(\\s*BIRTHDAY.*)");
        while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {                                
                 Matcher comment = pattern[4].matcher(line);
                 Matcher err = error.matcher(line);
                 Matcher leg = legit.matcher(line);
                 Matcher name = pattern[0].matcher(line);
                 Matcher age = pattern[1].matcher(line);
                 Matcher addr = pattern[2].matcher(line);
                 Matcher bd = pattern[3].matcher(line);
                 Matcher input = pattern[a].matcher(line);
                 if (!input.find() && (comment.find() || err.find() || (leg.find() && (!name.find() && !age.find() && !addr.find() && !bd.find())))               
                     continue;
                    Matcher dp = pattern[a].matcher(line);
                    dpla = dp.find();
                    break;
                 }
        }
        return dpla;
     }
```

Works exactly like I wanted :D

Answer (score 2):

Lets simply go for some different approach. I think, in essence, you have some input strings; and then you have a list of different regexes that can potentially contain matchers you are interested in. You are doing a lot of matching in your code, to finally return only a boolean; which doesn't seem to useful; so I am going to give you an idea how to do things differently.

```
 class RegexListMatcher {
   private final Map<String, Pattern> patternsById;
   private final String inputToMatchOn;

   private final String matchingId;
   private final String matchResult;

   RegexListMatcher(Map<String, Pattern> patternsById, inputToMatchOn) {
     this.patterns... = patterns
     this.input... = input

     matchingId = findMatchingId();
     if (matchingId == null) {
        matchResult = null;
     } else {
        matchResult = getMatchResult();
     }
   }

   private final String findMatchingId() {
     for (Entry<String, Pattern> entry : patternsById) {
       if entry.value matches the given input return entry.key

     otherwise return null
   }

   private final String getMatchResult() {
     Pattern pattern = patternsById.get(matchingId);
     return the value matched within input 
   }

   public boolean hasMatch() { return matchingID != null; }
   public String getMatchId() ...
   public String getMatchResult() ...
```

To be used like:

```
 private final static Map<String, Pattern> RULES = new HashMap<>();
 RULES.put("NAME", Pattern.compile("^\\s*(NAME\\:\\s*)\\s(\\w+)"));
 ...

 RegexListMatcher listMatcher = new RegexListMatcher(RULES, someInputString);
 if (listMatcher.hasMatch()) { 
   one of the rules matched
 } else {
   no match at all
 }
```

The key point in my implementation: you have a list of potential patterns; and if one of those matches, you surely are interested in the value matched within your input. And surprise: if none of the patterns matched, then you know that, too. Because the RegexListMatcher can tell you so.

Sure, more code than yours; but for example: there isn't any hardcoded access to a certain array index at all. Obviously, the above is partially pseudo code, but I guess it should be good enough to get you started.